# How to display errors from server side with jQuery blueimp File Upload plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, blueimp

I'm working on a project that use  [blueimp jQuery-File-Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

I can't display errors that occurs on server-side as it just display  `Empty file upload result`.

that's the jQuery template for displaying uploaded files

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2">
              <span class="label label-important">
                {%=locale.fileupload.error%}
              </span>
              {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}
            </td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% } %}


    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

I want to know how to access directly the json or any other way to get the error message that I already sent from the backend!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use the chrome Inspector to watch the JSON returned by your backend (XHR tab) so then you know how to access it from the template.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of callback options you can use with this plugin - see the docs here:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

For errors, you probably want:

```
.bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
```

or

```
.bind('fileuploadchunkfail', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
```

if you're using chunked uploads....